# How can my team use a single SuperPuTTY session file?

Tags: windows, putty, sysadmin

I work in a team that uses SuperPuTTY (on Windows) to connect to remote devices. We currently use our own session files, but not everyone notifies the team when a new device needs to be added/removed from our session files.

How can my team use one session file without overwriting each-other's changes?

Answer (score 0):

According [to the documentation](https://github.com/jimradford/superputty/wiki/Documentation#configuration-file--settings-storage) there are two places where the settings file can be stored:

- %USERPROFILE%
- the location of the .exe file

So the only viable option I see is to place the .exe file and the config on a network share and have everybody use this .exe instead of a local installed version.

Placing both in a folder managed by something like NextCloud/OneDrive/Dropbox might work, but could result in conflicts.

One way or the other, this will not only affect sessions but all settings, since they are stored in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Would the 'Make available offline'-feature be of any help?

As in: place the .exe and the settings in a shared network folder, and leave the synchronising up to  the OS

...actually, after perusing the source code, it seems that using the command-line `SuperPutty.exe -load SETTINGS` might load the settings from whatever *SETTINGS* points to?